# Select Var out of String

Tags: powershell

My task is to make an array with color values and some code names, and in a file I have to search and replace them.

Search and replace simple values are easy but, what I want to do is to test if the path is available. So I have to test 2 paths. And on 3 drives (C:, D:, E:).

Here are the paths:

> X:\oracle\wl\user_projects\domains\e92apps\servers\JDEWE202_PY\stage\JDEWE202_PY\app\webclient.war\share\css\webclient.css
>
> X:\jde_home\SCFHA\targets\JDEWE202_PY\owl_deployment\webclient.ear\app\webclient.war\share\css\webclient.css

Important is that the path is always the same but `JDEWE202_PY` could also be something like `MS_XXX383` and I have to find out if it's PY or MS. So all the values are:

- MS
- PY
- DV
- PY2
- MS2

This is the array that I created:

```
$arr = @{}
$arr["Type"] = @{}
$arr["Type"]["name"] = @{}
$arr["Type"]["name"]["MS"] = "f6902d"
$arr["Type"]["name"]["PY"] = "a40000"
$arr["Type"]["name"]["DV"] = "0b8d23"
$arr["Type"]["name"]["MS2"] = "01abaa"
$arr["Type"]["name"]["PY2"] = "80628b"
```

I created a `foreach` loop which checks the paths with a `Test-Path`. But my problem is that it always it's giving out False.

My code looks like this:

```cs
foreach ($vor in $prefix) {
    $paths = Test-Path -Path $vor+"\oracle\wl\user_projects\domains\e92apps\servers", $vor+"\jde_home\SCFHA\targets\"
    $paths
}
Join-Path -Path $paths
```

Comment: FTR, what you created is called hashtable, not array, and it's easier to create it inline, like this: `$arr = @{"Type" = @{"name" = @{ "MS"="f6902d"; "PY"="a40000"; ...}}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

join-path inside foreach loop?

```
foreach ($vor in $prefix) {
  $pathone=join-path -path $vor -childpath 'oracle\wl\user_projects\domains\e92apps\servers'
  $pathtwo=join-path -path $vor -childpath 'jde_home\SCFHA\targets'

  test-path -path $pathone,$pathtwo -pathtype Container
}
```